# Need help with Jacobi symbol / quadratic nonresidues proof

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, jacobi-symbol

I've been doing a few number theory problems online for fun and I've been having a bit of trouble with proving this one successfully:

> Suppose $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes. Prove that there is always some integer $n$ with $(n / pq) = -1$ (where $(n / m)$ means the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) of $n$ and $m$).

I ended up with $(p/n)(q/n)$  and tried using the prime factorization of *n* to try to get somewhere, but I don't think it's the correct path. I think what I need to do is prove that there is always some *n* that can be a quadratic non-residue modulo *pq*. However, I've also been having a bit of trouble trying to prove this.

Could someone give a bit of guidance to help me out? Thanks.

Comment: e.g. choose $n\equiv c\,$ nonsquare $\!\!\pmod{\!p}\,$ and $\,n\equiv 1\pmod{\!q},\,$ e.g. $\ c+p(p^{-1}(1\!-\!c)\bmod q)\ \ $

Comment: @EMS  It is not appropriate to delete your question as soon as it is answered.  Such behaviour is disrespectful to the person(s) who took the time to answer, constitutes vandalism of the site, and is often indicative of attempts to cheat and hide the evidence.  Please don't do this again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with the prime factorization of $n$, apart from it being relatively prime to $pq$, but that is implicit in the equation you have. Also, instead of "$(p/n)(q/n)$", your symbols should be the reciprocal of this. In particular, rewriting your equation of [Jacobi symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) in terms of [Legendre symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) gives

$$\left(\frac{n}{pq}\right) = \left(\frac{n}{p}\right)\left(\frac{n}{q}\right) = -1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This means one of the Legendre symbol values is $1$ and the other is $-1$. Since $p$ and $q$ are odd primes, there's always at least one quadratic residue and one quadratic non-residue for each. Assume the first Legendre symbol value is $1$, so let $x$ be a quadratic residue modulo $p$, and the second one is $-1$, so let $y$ be a non-quadratic residue modulo $q$. You thus have the following $2$ congruence equations to solve for $n$:

$$n \equiv x \pmod p \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$n \equiv y \pmod q \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) states you can solve the above $2$ equations to get a unique solution of $n$ modulo $pq$.